# What does it exactly mean by "the argument is copied (or moved)" in vector::push_back() in the given code sample?

Tags: c++

My apology! The error has nothing to do with the original question (striked out now). I'm keeping this question as the comments are very helpful on the design level to avoid any future confusion.

<strike>I'm trying to figure out exactly what is copied when there're nested containers.</strike>

The code snippet below has a vector of `stack< int> *`. I was assuming that when a pointer to `stack<int>` is `push_back()`'d to a vector, the memory address is copied. Then when you deref the pointer, it'll point to the same `stack< int>`. Therefore, if you pushed `int`s to that stack before its pointer is `push_back()`'d to the vector, you'll still be able to access those values afterwards.

```
void SetOfStacks::push(const int _val) {
    if (-1 == active_stack ||
        (stacks[active_stack])->size() == stack_threshold) { 
        std::stack<int> *s = new std::stack<int>();
        //QUESTION: if s->push(_val) happends before s is push_back'd to stacks. 
        //          s would appear to be empty after it's push_back'd
        stacks.push_back(s);
        active_stack++;
    }
    stacks[active_stack]->push(_val); //modification to the stack is 
    //valid after its pointer is push_back'd
}
```

The question is written as a comment in the code above.

Comment: Allocating a dynamic data structure with `new` is a red flag. Why not resize `stacks` 1 higher (or push_back an empty stack, so there is nothing to worry about copying) and then push directly into the stack stored inside your data structure. Then you don't need to worry about any pointers.

Comment: @NeilKirk, Thank you for the comment. Yours and JVene's suggestion on using shared_ptr are both better designs than the pointer-based design in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given, presumably, some container storing stacks as in:

```
std::vector< std::stack<int> * > stacks;
```

We see a questionable but valid storage strategy. We find elsewhere in code this strategy assumes the vector above owns the stacks put into it. Ownership is defined, in this discussion, as responsible for deleting dynamically allocated objects. If vector falls from scope, it's storage is deleted. However, the stacks put into it would not be deleted, and would all be memory leaks (along with their contents). This storage strategy requires that prior to any deletion of the vector "stacks", some code must loop through each entry and explicitly delete the stack inside it.

That's a bad design choice.

However, solutions still leave the OP's question intact, which I'll get to shortly. First, to solve the storage strategy, consider:

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr< std::stack<int>> > stacks;
```

The vector is still theoretically storing pointers, but now they're smart pointers and manage the ownership of each stack within. There will be no memory leaks, and no copies of the stacks (just the shared pointers are copied).

Now, about:

```
if (...whatever...)
    { 
        std::shared_ptr<stack<int>> s( new std::stack<int>() );

        stacks.push_back(s);
        active_stack++;
    }

    stacks[active_stack]->push(_val);
```

This version is for the suggested change to shared_ptr usage, leaving the original question intact. What about "s".

It is true that pushing content into s prior to pushing s into stacks means that such content will be visible afterwards at `stacks[active_stack]`. That is, `stacks[active_stack]` is providing the exact same stack pushed into the vector, not a copy.

This is because the vector stores the stacks BY POINTER. Now, however, the latter version is by smart_pointer. The reason the question even comes to mind is simply that vectors copy what is placed into them. In these cases (the OP's or the shared_ptr version) are copying ONLY the pointers. What those pointers point TO is not copied.

With all of that said, from a design standpoint one should question why create a dynamic container like this? There can be reasons, and they're rare, but do you have one?

Put another way, why would this not suit the purposes just as well?

```
std::vector< std::stack<int> > stacks;
```

Most containers must copy what is pushed into them, but copies are often elided by optimizers. If the purpose of storing pointers to containers in the vector is to avoid this copying of each stack pushed into it, it may not matter. Vectors function like arrays, and if the copy is elided, there is no copy, no performance implication, but a much simpler storage strategy.

However, there can be other reasons. For example:

```
std::map< int, std::stack<int> > stacks;
```

The iterators for map are more complicated, and copies are tossed around frequently. They, too, might be elided if the effect of not copying produces no results, but that can be tricky to rely upon with map. For this, it may be best to use a shared_ptr to store a dynamically allocated stack, rather than a stack.

One good reason to use shared_ptr to store containers is for something like a list handed across threads, or which may be pulled out of one container and put into another (trading containers around). The only way to be able to consider a container as an object which can be plucked out of one container and handed over to another is if that container is owned by something like a shared_ptr.

More commonly, though, such containers are members of other objects, which themselves may be "owned" by shared_ptrs, effectively resulting in a similar idea.

Comment: Dear @JVene, thank you so much for the great answer! I've learned the shared_pointer awhile ago, but have yet to be comfortable using it in my code where it's needed. Your answer provides an excellent explanation on this topic.

Comment: As for the `push()` to `stack` before `push_back()` to the `stacks`, I'm not sure if I understand it. Maybe my knowledge on pointers is fundamentally flawed: While the `stacks` owns the stacks by POINTER, `stacks[index]`, when dereferenced, should be the same stack that was dynamically alloc'd. Therefore, the changes made to `stack` BEFORE it's `push_back()` should still be there, despite that the actual 'stack' is not owned by the `stacks`. But the reality is when `stacks[index]` is deferenced, the previously `push()`'d values are gone.

Comment: @K.G. what previously pushed values? When the new stack is pushed into stacks, it is empty. The result should be that stacks[ active_stack ] returns exactly the stack that was just pushed, and empty stack. How is it you see previously pushed material gone? Can you post an example in the original question to clarify that observation?

Comment: my apologies. Upon careful debugging, I found that the error is generated elsewhere due to an inconsistency of the `active_stack` and the actually indices of the `stacks`. I'll go back and edit my original post. Thank you for your great comment on shared_ptr and more!

Comment: Sounds like what I expected. Glad it helped.